# How to count the number of files inside a tar.gz file (without decompressing)?

Tags: compression, gzip, tar

I have a tar.gz file which I have made by pigz (parallel gzip). I wanted to count the number of files inside the compressed file without decompressing it.

I use this command:

```
tar -tzf file.tar.gz
```

but I got an error:

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
```

Is it because I used pigz instead of gzip?  If yes how can I count the them now?

Comment: That should work.  You need to show exactly how you made the .tar.gz file.  pigz vs. gzip would not make any difference here, assuming it was done properly.

Comment: By the way, it is necessary to decompress and you are decompressing with the `tzf`.  Perhaps you mean without storing the resulting files.

Comment: `pigz` and `gzip` are two implementations of the same compression scheme, so that would not be the issue.

Answer (score 40):

Since it is a tar and gzip archive you should use `z` option to use gzip. Then simply you can count lines with `wc`.

```
tar -tzf file.tar.gz | wc -l
```

Comment: This answer gave the same file count as `gzip -cd file.tar.gz | tar -tvv | grep -c ^-` but twice as fast: 8.5 minutes compared to 17 minutes on a 6GB archive.

Comment: @cw' not the same exactly, it counts folders too, not only files

Answer (score 8):

you can use the tar -vv verbose option twice for full verbose, then grep the first character from file permissions. the ^ means only match first character (begin of line). the grep -c option count the lines.

```
drwxrwx--x   directory
lrwxrwxrwx   symlink
-rw-rw----   file
```

count regular files only

```
gzip -cd file.tar.gz | tar -tvv | grep -c ^-
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

I used unpigz for those files and it changed the file extensions to .tar . after that I could use tar -tzf without any problems.

Thanks!

Comment: That means that you erroneously compressed it twice.  If `tar -tzf` worked, then that file was a `tar.gz` file.  As I said in my comment, you need to provide exactly how you created the file in the first place.

Comment: I did! I started my question with "I have a tar.gz file which I have made by pigz (parallel gzip)"

Comment: aha! sorry it was my miss understanding.                            tar czf - folder | pigz -9 -p 32 > file.tar.gz

Comment: That's what I figured.  You are compressing _twice_.  Your mistake is using `z` in the `tar` command.  You are compressing with gzip with that `z`, and then a second time with pigz.  Instead you need to: `tar cf - folder | pigz -9 -p 32 > file.tar.gz`.  That will compress just _once_ using pigz instead of gzip, and then your `tar -tzf` will work.